# Query filter: array property length less than the value of another property

Tags: mongodb

Schema

```
{
useLimit: Number,
uses: [{...}]
}
```

I'd like to query this collection matching only those documents where the length of uses is less than useLimit or useLimit is -1 (representing infinite)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it, is to make use of the `$where` operator in the `find()` query:

```
// pass a function to the `$where` operator, to pick records 
// if they meet the desired condition. 
db.collection.find( {
    $where : function() {
        return (this.uses.length < this.useLimit || this.useLimit == -1);
    }
})
```

or using the `aggregation` pipeline,

- Project a field `isValid` for each document, with its value resolving
  to `true` or `false`. `true`, if the condition is met, else `false`.
- The next step is to match all the documents with the `isValid`
  attribute with value `true`.
- Finally the `$project` operator projects the fields other than
  `isValid`.

as below,

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ {
    $project : {
        "uses" : 1,
        "useLimit" : 1,
        "isValid" : {
            $cond : [ {
                $or : [ {
                    $gte : [ "$useLimit", {
                        $size : "$uses"
                    } ]
                }, {
                    $eq : [ "$useLimit", -1 ]
                } ]
            }, true, false ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match : {
        "isValid" : true
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        "uses" : 1,
        "useLimit" : 1
    }
} ])
```